# Migration from svn to git with change in folder structure

Tags: git, github, git-svn

We are in process of migrating from svn to git and started with small projects. We are using `git svn clone` for migration. For a while, we would like to have both svn & git. We use `git svn rebase` to get latest code changes from subversion. In one of our svn project, we would like to clone into a different directory/folder structure in git. I tried doing this

1) First cloned the entire project from svn, and had put into our github.
2) Made my desired folder structure in git, by moving folders around.
3) Re-based from SVN. When I did this, along with existing new folder structure, older folder structure restored which  don`t want to have.

Prior to this, I tried cloning each svn folder, but given up thought as each svn clone leading to create a new git repo. Can anybody help with this? Thanks!

**P.S**: The major reason we want to change folder structure is, we have ant as a build tool until now where we have a non-conventional folder structure. We are migrating to gradle and would like to have a conventional folder structure

Comment: Have you tried to "freeze development" on your SVN repository temporarily, `git mv` the files, `git svn dcommit` to push your moves back into SVN, then open up development again? I think the key here will be to get those moves into your upstream repository.

Comment: @Chris Thanks it helped. I just created another branch named "restore" initially. Changed folder structure using <code>git mv</code>  in "restore" branch. In master, I am re-basing from svn and in "restore" branch we are merging changes from master branch.